# AvPlayerItem currentTime's value is negative and player plays really fast

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayeritem

I am developing a video player on iOS using AvPlayer. A bug bother me. Sometimes the player plays the video really fast and i don't know why. And I noticed that the AvPlayerItem currentTime's value is negative. Can anyone help me and give me some option?

Comment: Check if you are playing the item only right after its status is set to Ready, there are some examples on Apple site.

Comment: Thank you for your answer..it may be the problem. Instead playing the item immediately I use a dispatch_after right after the status is set to ready. Now it works.

Comment: It could do the trick, but is not the correct way and probably it can fail on different devices or iOSes. You need to add an observer to the status property of an AVItem.